# RHEL8 /usr/bin/su: Permission denied

Tags: linux, permissions

Have a custom system service to run on boot up,

run in `systemctl start` get error

```
/etc/init.d/Startservice: line 2: /usr/bin/su: Permission denied
```

Exec Startservice script, manually run `Startservice` with root is fine

```
#!/bin/bash 
su -c  '/infa/pwc/tomcat/bin/service.sh startup' - infaap
```

Here is the  ServiceName.service in `/usr/lib/systemd/system/`

```
[Unit]
enter code here`Description=Auto Run infaservice and register to service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
RemainAfterExit=yes
#User=user
#Group=group
#WorkingDirectory=/path/to/folder
ExecStart=/etc/init.d/Startservice
#TimeoutSec=0s
#Restart=always
#RestartSec=5s

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Selinux is not the solution because security issue.

How can I do next

**UPDATE:**

```
[Unit]
Description=Auto Run infaservice and register to service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
RemainAfterExit=yes
User=infaap
Group=infaap
#WorkingDirectory=/path/to/folder
ExecStart=/infa/pwc/tomcat/bin/infaservice.sh startup
ExecStop=/infa/pwc/tomcat/bin/infaservice.sh shutdown
#TimeoutSec=0s
#Restart=always
#RestartSec=5s

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

After exec script directly, got this message

```
OpenInfa.service: Failed to execute command: Permission denied
OpenInfa.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /infa/pwc/tomcat/bin/infaservice.sh: Permission denied
```

Comment: ...but why are you using `su` at all? And why do you have an /etc/init.d/Startservice at all? Why not just put the same Tomcat command directly in ExecStart?

Comment: I need user profile to start the service, I've tried add User=xxx in the [Service], it shows permission denied to exec spawning /infa/pwc/tomcat/bin/infaservice.sh

Comment: That actually sounds like infaservice.sh is just missing the +x flag. (It can't be another kind of permission issue because if it were, then it would have affected 'su' as well.) What if you `chmod +x` it, or alternatively use `ExecStart=/bin/sh /infa/pwc/...service.sh start`?

Comment: again, if all that infaservice.sh does is run `/infa/pwc/tomcat/bin/service.sh startup`, **you just shouldn't use that script at all**, as multiple people have told you now :) As a matter of fact, it *cannot* work if you run `infaservice.sh` as infaap. That makes no sense – all that infaservice.sh does is use superuser privileges to run `service.sh`  als `infaap`. **you don't need infaservice.sh**.

Answer (score 1):

why do you run `su`? That makes no sense – instead, just specify that you want the service to be started by user `infaap`; you even commented out the `User=` line that would have done that for you:

```ini
[Unit]
Description=Auto Run infaservice and register to service
After=network.target

[Service]
# `simple` is almost certainly not the type you want when starting
# something as complex as tomcat. I *bet* you meant `forking`!
Type=forking

User=infaap
# make sure this is the group name you want to use
Group=infaap

ExecStart=/infa/pwc/tomcat/bin/service.sh startup
# I guess stopping works something like this?
ExecStop=/infa/pwc/tomcat/bin/service.sh shutdown

# But honestly, tomcat's start and stop usually look different.
# so I think your `service.sh` is just yet another layer
# of indirection only needed for sysv-init, but not for 
# systemd. Instead, you'd want to use something like this:
# ExecStart=/infa/pwc/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
# ExecStop=/infa/pwc/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh

[Install]
# is this really the target you want this to belong to?
# Usually, you want `WantedBy=multi-user.target`
WantedBy=default.target
```

Comment: I need user profile to start the service, I've tried add User=xxx in the [Service], it shows permission denied to exec spawning /infa/pwc/tomcat/bin/infaservice.sh

Comment: then `su` could not have done it any better. Something is fishy about `infaservice.sh`, and as said, it looks like that script is completely superfluous.